# How to show notification badge without count in ios?

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How can we show empty badge in react-native iOS?
I just want to show the red dot on my app icon.

Comment: Have you ever seen something like that on **any non-apple app**?

Comment: I've seen this in android, but I'm not sure if iOS can do this or not.

Comment: Did you try alternateIcon ? You could design one with empty badge for your app